# Receiving half the value of Reference Voltage in AD7705?

Tags: arduino-nano, spi, adc

I have a doubt in the AD7705 library [AD7705 Library Link](http://www.kerrywong.com/2012/04/18/ad7705ad7706-library-revisited/comment-page-1/?unapproved=1271018&moderation-hash=8b80f04a3200d58d64eb86a598fc3c24#comment-1271018) when I am declaring a reference voltage of 5 V and giving a reference voltage of 5 V to IN1+. On the serial monitor, I can see ADC conversion from 2.5V to 5 V when I vary the potentiometer.

whatever reference voltage I am giving it is divided by 2.

What parameter should I change to get full-scale voltage reading?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: it is more than divided by two ... please include the schematic diagram of your circuit

Comment: If you saying you have a potentiometer, it is likely you had a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) in your circuitry, and you need to convert your ADC reading to get the actual value.